# How to customize System.Text.Json serialization of certain fields?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, .net-7.0

I need to (de)serialize objects which reference 3rd party API objects which arent serializable. However I dont need their content to be serialized. I just want to serialize Id of these objects and then retrieve them on deserailization.

Short example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Id;
    public I3rdParyObject Data;
}
```

I want a custom logic to be called on (de)serializing `Data`. I would write to text `"Data": "abc"` on serialization and retrieve it on deserialization like: `deserializedObject.Data = DataManager.GetDataById("abc")`

Comment: How do you extract `"abc"` from `I3rdParyObject`?  Is there some `public string Id { get; }` property?  Also is `I3rdParyObject` an interface type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the text `"abc"` can be extracted from `I3rdParyObject` itself, e.g. via some property:

```
public interface I3rdParyObject
{
    public string Id { get; }
    // Remainder not shown in your question
}
```

You can write a [custom `JsonConverter<I3rdParyObject>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to) for `I3rdParyObject` like so:

```
public class I3rdParyObjectConverter : JsonConverter<I3rdParyObject>
{
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, I3rdParyObject value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.Id);
    
    public override I3rdParyObject Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        DataManager.GetDataById(reader.GetString()!);
}
```

Or if the Id cannot be obtained directly from `I3rdParyObject` but can be returned by `DataManager` using some method like:

```
public static class DataManager
{
    public static string GetDataId(I3rdParyObject obj) => /* Logic to get the Id */
}
```

Then `WriteJson()` could be written as follows:

```
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, I3rdParyObject value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteStringValue(DataManager.GetDataId(value));
```

Then add the converter to `JsonSerializerOptions` during serialization like so when serializing or deserializing:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new I3rdParyObjectConverter() },
    // Other options as required
    IncludeFields = true,  // You must set this if MyClass.Id and MyClass.Data are really fields not properties.
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myClass, options);
var myClass2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(json, options);
```

Notes:

- In your question, you state that `MyClass.Id` and `MyClass.Data` are **fields**.  By default, System.Text.Json does not serialize fields.  If these members are really fields and not properties, you must enable serialization of fields, e.g. by setting [`JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields?view=net-7.0).

  For more see [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET: Include fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#include-fields).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NXMOTo).